# How to change the KEYSTORE securely?

Tags: android, game-maker, version-control

I'm wanting to release a free version of an app to which I've already made a paid version.

I simply copied the project to another folder:

[image]

The project is initially the same as the paid application when finalized. I want to simply delete a few phases and put a link that takes the application paid in the Google Store (this I know how to do);

Turns out there is something called a keystore.

[image]

I would like to know if only thing I have to do is create a **file.keystore** in the directory with different name, rename the Filename (before **Password**) and click the generate button (below **Country**).

OBS - Obviously I will make a backup copy of the paid version **file.keystore**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I changed the first field (**filename**).

Then I clicked on button **generate**.

The program has created a new key in a different location than where I put the keys.

Just copy or move the key to the place of your choice.

Be very careful not to create a new key without having made a copy of the previous one. Otherwise, **you may be unable to update your game in the Play Store**.